# How to get the hidden input's value by using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, findall

How can i get input value from html page

like

```
<input type="hidden" name="captId" value="AqXpRsh3s9QHfxUb6r4b7uOWqMT" ng-model="captId">
```

I have input name [ name="captId" ] and need his value

```
import re , urllib ,  urllib2
a = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/','').read()
```

thanx

---

update 1

I installed BeautifulSoup and used it but there some errors

code

```
 import re , urllib ,  urllib2
 a = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/','').read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
 value = soup.find('input', {'name': 'scnt'}).get('value')
```

error

"soup = BeautifulSoup(a)
NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined"

Comment: You get the value of a hidden input the same way you get any other input.

Comment: yes but what i use re.findall or re.search and how writing true pattern

Comment: BeautifulSoup should be what you need : you first select the form, then the hidden fields.

Comment: @IBRA I misunderstood, I thought you were talking about the script that the form posts to, not a web scraping script.

Comment: @Barmar yes i want to send post to url and get info in the input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `re` module to parse xml or html is generally considered as bad practice. Use it only if **you** are responsable for the page you try to parse. If not, either your regexes are awfully complex, or your script could break if someone replaces `<input type="hidden" name=.../>` with `<input name="..." type="hidden" .../>` or almost anything else.

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a html parser that :

- automatically fixes minor errors (unclosed tags ...)
- build a DOM tree
- allows you to browse the tree, search for specific tags, with specific attributes
- is useable with Python 2 and 3

Unless you have good reasons not to do it, you should use it rather than `re` for HTML parsing.

For example assuming that `txt` contains the whole page, find all hidden fields would be as simple as :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
hidden_tags = soup.find_all("input", type="hidden")
for tag in hidden_tags:
    # tag.name is the name and tag.value the value, simple isn't it ?
```

Comment: @IBRA There are plenty of them in referenced sited ... But see my edit anyway

Comment: I have the the complete tag using your code snippet but I am not sure how to use this to get the data I need.

Comment: @deepaksen: it is a quite old post by now. Are you sure you just want to comment, or would you like to ask a new question giving this post as a reference for your current research?

Comment: sure i will do this way