# How to extract info using a form-data from form tag in html

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

Website link : https://www.cdw.com/search/software/?b=mic&w=f&pcurrent=1

I have to fetch "MS MPSAD SYS CTR SRV CNFG MGR LSA" from the pop up which appears after clicking on add to cart.

Basic Question is how to deal with pop up content when clicking generates the pop up

which comes from the tag as follows:

```
<form action="/cart/addtocart/" class="addToCartForm cart-top-addtocart-by-edc" data-addtocartasync="/cart/addtocartasync/" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="sB_lUL7jwTaTOwC5W0fGHnj_xjPtIKzkJPeHuQejajSQq06Sz2hlY8i-LMlfrnQ0GwxJeGwc7tQ6SIu2HGhQD821fB41"/>
<input name="ProductContext.ProductCode" type="hidden" value="3667016"/>
```

[How to get the hidden input's value by using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489296/how-to-get-the-hidden-inputs-value-by-using-python/30489599?noredirect=1#comment110808053_30489599)
I have tried getting values from input of hidden type but i am not sure sure how i can proceed with the same.

Here I am using inspect element for URL and FORM Data
[image]

I am using postman to get response but response is null.
[image]

Comment: @SergeBallesta Can you help in this

Comment: Maybe for dynamic content you need selenium. But I’m not an expert in that.

Comment: Thanks, I have started trying selenium will update if resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def api_call(product_code, pricekey, token):
url = "https://www.cdw.com/cart/addtocartasync/"
payload = {'CartItems[0][Quantity]': '1',
'CartItems[0][Product][ProductCode]': int(product_code),
'CartItems[0][SelectedPrice][PriceKey]': str(pricekey),
'__RequestVerificationToken': str(token)}
files = [

]

response = requests.request("POST", url, data = payload, files = files)
try:
    res = json.loads(response.text)
    return res['cartItems'][0]['product']['name']
except:
    return None
```

We can hit the api with post method with relevant info from the html and get the desired info.
As you can see the below inspector screenshot, we can get all the info from it.

[image]